# OneDrive will not allow folder to stop syncing

Tags: windows, onedrive

I have a few repositories setup on my machine and OneDrive is interfering with me doing npm installs and running build scripts due to it locking files at random or not granting access even when I give my process administrative privilege and/or use sudo in WSL. As a potential solution, I tried having OneDrive exclude the repos, but it refuses to do so. It is stuck on two files in one of the repos because of how those files are named (ex: .DS_STORE), but then will not let me delete them or rename them. At one point, I did manage to do so, and then OneDrive restored them, but gave me the same errors! It will not let me exclude the repos unless it finishes backing them up, and it will not finish backing them up unless these files it does not like are also backed up. All I get when I try to exclude the directories is this:

[image]

How infuriating. I do no want OneDrive to sync these folders, but it will not let me not sync them until they are synced. Is there some other way I can go about clearing up these issues? I never had problems with OneDrive before I had to re-install Windows 10 recently, but now it is so aggressive that it seems to want to back up almost everything on my computer whether I want it to or not.

Comment: Have you tried stopping the OneDrive services?

Comment: I ended up unlinking my account, but this had the undesired effect of wiping out literally everything stored locally in my documents folder. I'm fed up with it and am in the process of creating a new local account and manually copying all my files over.